# ClassNotFound in Embedded-Jetty and Maven

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jetty

To do some Surface-Tests I start an embedded Jetty for JUnit-Tests. My tests call some pages from the server. When doing this tests from eclipse everything works fine, the classpath is created by "mvn eclipse:eclipse".

When running those tests with "mvn test" the jsp-Compiler raises a lot of ClassNotFoundExceptions: javax.servlet., javax.servlet.jsp and evene some of my self generated classes. All requests directly answered by servlet work fine.

Doing in my testcases something like System.out.println(HttpServlet.class) works fine, too. So the Jetty-JSP compiler seems to habe some "specials" when compiling.

Anybody knows how to persuade Jetty to compile my JSPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the problem seems to have been in mavens dependency-management (or what I allowed maven to do).

I had a real mess of javax-artifacts in my classpath (jsp-2.1, 2.2.3, 2.2.1, servlet 2.5, 3.0, 3.0.glassfish-style). So after I cleaned up dependencies everything works fine. Now I understand why jetty from maven-.build didnn't start. Finally I dont understand why at all jetty came up in eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin for that:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Jspc_Maven_Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If in any way possible I would like to start jetty as embedded server from my testcases so developers can just rightclick in eclipse to start their tests

Comment: yes, absolutely, we do that all the time in jetty itself, there are lots of examples in jetty test cases of embedded jetty usage, and there is this tutorial : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Answer (score 0):

If you look [pom of one jetty module](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/8.1.7.v20120910/jetty-servlets-8.1.7.v20120910.pom) you'll see:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It dependes on own servlet-api classes.

So maybe if you specify dependencies on real servlet-api in your project pom it will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the servlet classes we depend on are the same as the original spec ones, they are just repackaged for eclipse reasons, they are signed and packed and the manifest has been cleaned up for OSGI usage, so this is a red herring